# Android smoothly rotate on surfaceView with respect to user

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas, flip

In Android, how to give draw a rotating/flipping coin wrt user on `SurfaceView`. It's very easy to use an animation and show the flipping coin in an `ImageView`, but I require this on `SurfaceView` with the same smoothness. Is there any way that I can give flipping animation in an `ImageView` then take out its content at every instant and then draw it on the `SurfaceView` continuously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Matrix class to perfom these operation on drawing bitmap.

something like

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Matrix needleTransMatrix = new Matrix();
    needleTransMatrix.postRotate(rotationAngle,needleImage.getWidth()/2,needleImage.getHeight());
    needleTransMatrix.postTranslate( centerX+METER_OFFSET-needleImage.getWidth()/2, centerY-needleImage.getHeight());

    Matrix dialTransMatrix = new Matrix();
    dialTransMatrix.postRotate(rotationAngle,dialImage.getWidth()/2,dialImage.getHeight()/2);
    dialTransMatrix.postTranslate( METER_OFFSET,0);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bgImage, METER_OFFSET, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(dialImage, dialTransMatrix, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(needleImage, needleTransMatrix, paint);
```

The below is the drawing thread about which i am talking about

```
private class AnimationThread extends Thread{

    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private int destinationNeedlePosition = NEEDLE_POSITION_ENQURIES;

    public AnimationThread(int destinationNeedlePosition) {
        this.destinationNeedlePosition = destinationNeedlePosition;
    }

    public void cancelAnimation(){
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int destinationAngle = destinationNeedlePosition *45;

        while(isRunning && destinationAngle != rotationAngle){
            if(destinationAngle > rotationAngle)
                rotationAngle++;
            else
                rotationAngle--;
            postInvalidate();
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yup i tried using matrix it can be used to get only one instant at a time by scalling .. that won't give a smooth flipping feel!!

Comment: you need to create a thread which would do transition from one position to another and interpolate the positions. The same thing I have done this way to rotate the needle of a meter.

Comment: why are you using the 2 matrices ?

Comment: Those are to animate two separate object in scene. I have not give you complete class that is the snippet from the class

Comment: oh what i what to achieve is a coin flipping wrt user ... smoothly ie each instant of the rotation should be visible . It seems that the code u have give would rotate the image ... The coin rotation i want should be like that somewhat similar to that of flipping page ... the coin should start flipping(reducing size from one edge) then at mid way edge pts 2 user den grows back reverse action happens 2 d othr edge!

Comment: I couldn't find anything the Matrix class to rotate it in z-direction. I would like to suggest you to do this using opengl. Refer the link below for basics. http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

Comment: is it somehow possible to get the coin to flip in an imageView. Then use a thread to extract the image in animation from the imageView at every instant and continuously display the extracted image on canvas

Comment: thanks for the instant help ... although this is not related to the above question it wud b gr8 deal 4 me if u help me out ... I am an indian so is there any way I can try out the in app billing feature in android ... i just wanna do it for learning purpose . The problem is google wallet's merchant account is not yet available for indians. Is there any testing account available for testing purpose!!

Comment: This would not be a good approach. I would recommend you opengl for doing this. As When we do animation on any view including ImageView with Animation class or its decedents That animation is done on overlay and the state does not persist.

Comment: No google has updated the list of countries. Now you can add merchant account from india as well.